# intermediate cert - to be install on webserver (why)?

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, certificate-authority, digital-signature

I understand the basic of asymmetric key, the storing of private key and the dissemination of your public key and information to be sign with the private key of the CA after verification (to get a cert for your site).   The public key of the CA should already come pre-installed/trusted with the browser.

But your cert might not be sign by a root CA (that is trusted by your browser), it might be sign by an intermediate CA and your browser might not have the public key of the intermediate CA that sign your cert

-> is this the reason why whenever i get a cert reply from a CA,there is always an option to download the intermediate certs and whenever i install my cert into my webserver (apache), i will need to install the intermediate cert as well

Comment: In short: your assumption is correct but I still consider it a duplicate to the question which asks what these "ca-bundle" is for.

Comment: yeap a definitely duplicate. thanks for the link and confirmation of my thoughts!